# How do you create a superuser using mongoengine?

Tags: django, mongodb, django-admin, mongoengine

I'm a bit confused how it works. I've done all the steps to replace Django's default authentication with mongoengine so that it uses mongodb and the database but I tried making a registration page and couldn't figure out how to user the superuser function. Currently I'm trying

```
newuser = UserManager.create_superuser(username=request.POST['username'],
                                       password=request.POST['password'],
                                       email=request.POST['email'])
newuser.save()
```

But I keeps giving me the error

```
TypeError at /registerSuper/

unbound method create_superuser() must be called with UserManager instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set up the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` like so:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL=('mongo_auth.MongoUser')
```

You can then use django to return the user model and then use the manager on that:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(**user_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

in your settings.py

```
    import mongoengine

    INSTALLED_APPS = (
        ...
        'mongoengine.django.mongo_auth',
    )

    AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
        'mongoengine.django.auth.MongoEngineBackend',
    )
    MONGOENGINE_USER_DOCUMENT = 'mongoengine.django.auth.User'
    AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'mongo_auth.MongoUser'
```

Then you can usage standart way ./manage.py createsuperuser

Answer (score 0):

Typically Managers are accessed through the model and not called directly.

```
User.objects.create_superuser(...)
```

Comment: When I try this it tells me
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'create_superuser'

Comment: I've never used MongoEngine. As @Elliott mentions above, does this line work? `MongoUser.objects.create_superuser()`?

Comment: Well the mongoengine user class is called User as well. I just made sure to import that instead of django's. So the example I gave is using the mongoengine user class

Answer (score 0):

The error essentially means that you're trying to call a non-static method like it was a static method. Specifically, it's saying you need to call `create_superuser()` on an instance of UserManager, not on the UserManager class itself.

If you're using the default User model then User.objects will be an instance of UserManager, so you would call `User.objects.create_superuser(...)`. You're probably using the user model provided by mogoengine, so I would try importing the mongoengine user class and then trying `MongoUser.objects.create_superuser()`